# Connection Pool and Database Availability

Tags: spring, database-connection, connection-pooling, couchbase

If I've a connection pool to the DB and the DB is restarted, the connections become invalid. Why? The DB hostname hasn't changed. How can I detect this situation and purge the invalid connections?
The DB in my case is Couchbase but I'd think that this is a general problem. We're using Spring framework with Couchbase Java client for the following.

Couchbase configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfiguration {
    private Cluster cluster;

    @Value("${couchbase.nodes}")
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private String nodes;

    @Value("${couchbase.adminUsername}")
    private String adminUsername;

    @Value("${couchbase.adminPassword}")
    private String adminPassword;

    private static final long CONNECT_TIMEOUT = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10);

    @Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private Func2<CouchbaseEnvironment, List<String>, Cluster> clusterFactory = CouchbaseCluster::create; //NOPMD

    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct() {
        List<String> nodes = asList(this.nodes.split(",")).stream().map(String::trim).collect(toList());

        CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT)
                .bootstrapCarrierEnabled(false).build();

        cluster = clusterFactory.call(env, nodes);
    }

    @Bean
    Cluster cluster() {
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    ClusterManager clusterManager() {
        return cluster.clusterManager(adminUsername, adminPassword);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void preDestroy() {
        cluster.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Couchbase usage:

```
@Autowired
private Cluster cluster;

@Bean
Bucket bucket() {
    return cluster.openBucket(bucketName, bucketPassword);
}
```

Comment: I have not worked with `Couchbase ` but additional information would help to answer and locate the problem - like how you creating connection pools? connections are in the context of an application server or standalone app?language used?  e.g. connections don't get closed on db restart if DB2 is used along with JBoss but get closed if Postgres is used along with JBoss.

Comment: @SabirKhan I've updated my question with additional info.

Comment: Sorry, no Idea about your question. As far as I can read, there is no connection pooling in traditional RDBMS sense for couchbase.